# Can not prepend data to JSON file via jQuery and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I have a form with 3 inputs (one, which has an actual date as value, is not visible). My task is to prepend this three input values to a JSON file, which already has some data.

So, now after clicking submit button I get modal toggle and nothing happens. But normally it should prepend data to JSON file, close current modal and open another modal. How can I make it working?

Thank you for advance.

Here is my modal dialog with inputs:

```
<!-- Add a new report modal -->
<div id="add_report" class="modal fade " tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header"
                 style="border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-right: -0.5px; background-color: #2c2c2c; text-transform: uppercase; color: white; padding-left: 30px; padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 15px">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" style="color: white"><span
                        aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Leave report</h4>
            </div>
            <form method="post">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p><label for="report_name" style="margin-bottom: 5px">Name</label> <br>
                        <input id="report_name" style="width: 50%" type="text" name="name" required="required"
                               placeholder="name..."/>
                        <input id="report_date" style="width: 40%; visibility: hidden;" type="text">
                    </p>

                    <label for="report_message" style="margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 5px">Report</label> <br>
                    <textarea id="report_message" name="message" placeholder="report..."></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <h5 style="color: black; text-align: left">Fill all the fields please</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <button id="report_submit" type="submit" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title"
                                    data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">
                                Leave report
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Here is my script:

```
<script>
    $('#report_submit').on('click', function () {
        var $btn = $(this).button('loading')
        // business logic...
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Variable to hold request
            var request;

            // Bind to the submit event of our form
            $("#report_submit").submit(function (event) {

                // Prevent default posting of form - put here to work in case of errors
                event.preventDefault();

                // Abort any pending request
                if (request) {
                    request.abort();
                }
                // setup some local variables
                var $form = $(this);

                // Let's select and cache all the fields
                var $inputs = $form.find("input");

                // Serialize the data in the form
                var serializedData = $form.serialize();

                // Let's disable the inputs for the duration of the Ajax request.
                // Note: we disable elements AFTER the form data has been serialized.
                // Disabled form elements will not be serialized.
                $inputs.prop("disabled", true);

                // Fire off the request to /mail.php
                request = $.ajax({
                    url: "add_report.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: serializedData
                });

                // Callback handler that will be called on success
                request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    // Log a message to the console
                    console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
                    $(function () {
                        $('#add_report').modal('toggle');
                    });
                    $(function () {
                        $('#normalModal').modal('show');
                    });
                });

                // Callback handler that will be called on failure
                request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    // Log the error to the console
                    console.error(
                        "The following error occurred: " +
                        textStatus, errorThrown
                    );
                });

                // Callback handler that will be called regardless
                // if the request failed or succeeded
                request.always(function () {
                    // Reenable the inputs
                    $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
                });
            });
        });

        $btn.button('reset')
    })
</script>
```

And php code:

```
<?php
$current_data = file_get_contents('reports.json');

$array_data   = json_decode($current_data, true);

$extra_data = array(
    'name' => $_POST["name"],
    'date' => $_POST["date"],
    'message' => $_POST["message"]
);
array_unshift($array_data, $extra_data);
$final_data = json_encode($array_data);
file_put_contents( 'reports.json', $final_data );
?>
```

JSON file has this structure:

```
{
  "reports": [
    {
      "name": "Alex",
      "date": "30.09.2017",
      "message": "some words 1"
    },
    {
      "name": "Polly",
      "date": "27.09.2017",
      "message": "some words 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I need to prepend data from the form to an existing JSON file and it does not works now. The question is - how to make it working? ))

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov personally there's no way I'm going to read through all of that code. But how big is your JSON file? If it's under a couple of a hundred objects it might be easiest to just handle it with js on the front end

Comment: @Shard currently it has 11 objects, but it will be much more in the future. If it is possible, could you give me an advice how to make it with js on frontend? At least I will learn something new and it could solve my current problem at least for now(until I don't have that much data).

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation, you simply pass the JSON to the front end. With js you use JSON.parse to convert the string to an object. Then you use Object.assign to merge the original JSON object with your new data. Then do whatever you need to do with it. To convert it back to a JSON string just run JSON.stringify on the object.

Comment: @Shard thank you, I will read about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found the problem and it was here:

```
<form method="post">
```

should have a path to the php file like:

```
<form method="post" action="some.php">
```